# Convergence in Probability of the minimum

Tags: self-study, convergence, extreme-value

This is a homework question. I think I have the correct answer, but I am not sure. Also, the wording sounds very awkward. Is there a better way to show this (or better way to word this)?

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be a random sample from $f_\theta(x)$, where $f_\theta(x)$ is a continuous density with support $[\theta,\infty)$. Show that the minimum converges in distribution to $\theta$, i.e. $X_{(1)}\overset{P}{\longrightarrow}\theta$.

MY ATTEMPT:

The distribution function is $F(x)=\int_\theta^x f_\theta(t)dt$. Now we find the distribution function of the minimum\begin{align*}
1-F_{X_{(1)}}(x) &= P(X_{(1)} > x) \\
&= P(X_1>x,\ldots, X_n>x)\\
&= P(X_1>x)^n\\
&= (1-F(x))^n\\
F_{X_{(1)}}(x) &= 1-\left(1-\int_\theta^x f_\theta(t)dt\right)^n
\end{align*} For $x< \theta, F(x)=0$ so therefore $F_{X_{(1)}}(x) = 1-(1-0)^n=0$ for all $n$. For $x\geq \theta$ suppose that $F(x) = c$ where $0\leq c \leq 1$. Now we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty} F_{X_{(1)}}(x) =\lim_{n\to\infty} 1-(1-F(x))^n = \lim_{n\to\infty} 1-(1-c)^n = 1$$ Therefore 
$$ F_{X_{(1)}}(x) \longrightarrow G(x) = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    1 & \quad \text{if $x\geq \theta$}\\
    0 & \quad \text{if $x < \theta$}
  \end{array} \right.$$ This is a distribution function which puts all probability on one point, $\theta$. Therefore $X_{(1)}\overset{D}{\longrightarrow} \theta$, and since $\theta$ is a constant, $X_{(1)}\overset{P}{\longrightarrow}\theta$.

Comment: The key ideas are all clearly displayed.  There is a tiny (but interesting) error, though: your conclusion can be false when $x=\theta$.  For instance, let $f_\theta(x)=(x-\theta)/2$ for $\theta\le x\le\theta+2$ and $f_\theta(x)=0$ otherwise. Then $F(\theta)=0,$ implying the limiting value of $F_{X_{[1]}}(x)$ is $0$, not $1$.  This is interesting because it highlights the importance of invoking the definition of *support* somewhere in the proof and because it reveals the nature of the convergence is a tiny bit trickier than you might think.

Comment: Hmm, is your example not excluded by the assumption that the support of $f$ is $[\theta,\infty)$?

Comment: The right endpoint makes no difference to the limiting distribution of the minimum.  If you prefer, use $f_\theta(x) = (x-\theta)\exp(\theta-x)$ when $x\ge \theta.$